# rake snorby:setup

Tags: rake

while running: 
rake snorby:setup
getting below error:

rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
bundle exec rake snorby:setup
```

this error derived from the fact that you have multiple versions of `rake` gem, even newer than the one required by your `Gemfile`.

You can see this by typing

```
gem list rake
```

that should print on your console something like this:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
```

since `rake` is a tool you launch from the outside of a Rails (bundler) environment, it cannot know anything about bundle version unless you explicitly specify to follow bundler's version directions with the `bundle exec` command.